# Tranfering files on google cloud platform.error

Tags: google-cloud-platform

i keep getting the following error when i use GCP storage transfer function.[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuEgh.png)

the URL i am using and my tsv is located there, here:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZDkQgCIrzGU-emfHiHYwsvj9i108iJVO/view?usp=sharing

I tried placing the tsv directly on cloud storage but received the same error. then i used the gs// address instead of the URL and got the following error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYKz7.png)

so it seems to have picked up the URL from looking at the error message,but what does it mean that the process was denied? Denied to read my file or to download the download. Also it looks like it is reading the link as a webpage rather than a txt file.hmmm

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem with permissions on the sink bucket [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/iam-transfer#source-permissions).

> The Storage Transfer Service uses a service account to move data into
> a Cloud Storage sink bucket. The service account must have certain
> permissions for the sink bucket:
>
> Permission    Description Use
>
> storage.buckets.get    Allows the service
> account to get the location of the bucket.    Always required.
>
> storage.objects.create    Allows the service account to add objects to
> the bucket.   Always required.
>
> storage.objects.delete Allows the service
> account to delete objects in the bucket.  Required if you set
> overwriteObjectsAlreadyExistingInSink or deleteObjectsUniqueInSink to
> true.
>
> storage.objects.list   Allows the service account to list objects
> in the bucket.    Required if you set
> overwriteObjectsAlreadyExistingInSink to false or
> deleteObjectsUniqueInSink to true.
>
> All of these permissions are
> contained in the roles/storage.legacyBucketWriter role, which you can
> assign to the service account. For a complete list of Cloud Storage
> roles and the permissions they contain, see IAM roles.

Comment: Did you followed exactly the documentation [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/create-url-list?hl=en_US&_ga=2.96534683.-566201694.1566725932&_gac=1.187287130.1573312481.CjwKCAiA5JnuBRA-EiwA-0ggPcNsK74vIL5VL5HW5uPiCcPdDwmnarGjfVlQK-4s0Kdx6WdbeGumohoCFxkQAvD_BwE) ?

Comment: Are you making sure that the hash is correct as well as the object size? Since it won't work if they do not match.

Also the error that you're seeing is an authorization error, meaning that there's a permission error, most probably in your bucket sink.